# Parental leave and reduced income with Bluecard

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have a bluecard in Germany. Will have a newborn soon. If I apply for parental leave, my income will go down below the bluecard threshold. Does this affect a validity of the bluecard permit?

Comment: Technically, it seems that there is no income requirement but only a salary requirement. For example, having an income above the threshold through investments, etc. doesn't help at all. It's a way to define the scope of the regulation and to check whether a specific position falls within this scope.

Comment: With parental leave, my understanding is that your work contract remains unchanged and you're entitled to return to your previous position (including salary) when you come back but I am not 100% sure that's how it's interpreted in practice (hence a comment and no answer).